# How can i stable size for every widget? qt desiger

Tags: user-interface, user-controls, qt4, qt-designer

Suppose i have some `widget`  in `qt designer`,i need to stable their size , it means i want to disable `resizable feature`. how i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if set to maximum, it will at least allow to make the dialog smaller.

[image]

would be one way, the other is inside your code using:

```
setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint);
```

soo long zai

Answer (score 1):

in `qt designer`, `right click` on your dialog, `select` size constraints > set maximum size and set minimum size

[image]